# MoonAPNS timing out is there a way of preventing this?

Tags: c#, timeout, moonapns

I have successfully been able to implement amendable push notifications to send to all of the apple devices that have downloaded the application.

I store all of the device ID's in a database.

However, the app that i am tying to send a push notification too currently times its self out.

I think it does this because of the amount of people who have downloaded the app. Therefore it takes longer to process.

Is there a way that i could prevent the time out from happening?